# Strimzi operator Kafka cluster ACL not enabling with type: simple

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-security, strimzi

We know to enable Kafka ACL property `authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer` to be added in `server.properties` but how to enable that if Kafka cluster is running by Strimzi operator?

From Strimzi documents I have come to know in order to enable authorization, need to enable below code for `kind: Kafka` under spec:

```
listeners:
      tls:
        authentication:
         type: tls
```

Full code @[kafka-zookeeper-apps-tls-enabled.yml](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zW85-fqBK5RaXrPt64FIgcxq8PnvsWR7OZ7tsgzmiXo/edit?usp=sharing)

Also the below code for `kind: KafkaUser`

```
authentication:
    type: tls
  authorization:
    type: simple
```

Full code@[example-consumer-deny-deployment-authentication-TLS-alias-SSL.yml](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yZvFonxNBmLifJNmsWDMwyJp9A_IgCgRArZToUR9M7g/edit?usp=sharing)

In above `example-consumer-deny-deployment-authentication-TLS-alias-SSL.yml` code although ACL `type: deny`
am still able to consume messages.

Problem is even with the above code I see in kafka **my-cluster-kafka-0** pod environment variable **KAFKA_AUTHORIZATION_TYPE=simple** is absent even the `authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer` is absent in `server.properties`

**Note:** No Warnings/Errors in log of **strimzi-cluster-operator** pod while deploying above code.

I am working on Strimzi for 1st time so please help me enabling ACL's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Kafka custom resource doesn't enable authorization because the `authorization` section is not in the right place. You need to add the `authorization` section like this:

```yaml
    listeners:
      tls:
        authentication:
          type: tls
      external:
        type: route
        authentication:
          type: tls
    authorization:
      type: simple
      superUsers:
        - CN=my-user
```

You can read more about it in the documentation: https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/full.html#assembly-kafka-authentication-and-authorization-deployment-configuration-kafka